# In Python, how do I construct a URL to test if my SQL Server instance is running?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, docker-compose, pytest, urllib3

I'm using Python 3.8 with the pytest-docker-compose plugin -- https://pypi.org/project/pytest-docker-compose/ .  Does anyone know how to write a URL that would eventually tell me if my SQL Server is running?

I have this docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.2"
services:

  sql-server-db:
    build: ./
    container_name: sql-server-db
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "password"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

but I don't know what URL to pass to my Retry object to test that the server is running.  This fails ...

```
import pytest
import requests
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
...

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def wait_for_api(function_scoped_container_getter):
    """Wait for sql server to become responsive"""
    request_session = requests.Session()
    retries = Retry(total=5,
                    backoff_factor=0.1,
                    status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504])
    request_session.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

    service = function_scoped_container_getter.get("sql-server-db").network_info[0]
    api_url = "http://%s:%s/" % (service.hostname, service.host_port)
    assert request_session.get(api_url)
    return request_session, api_url
```

with this exception

```
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
E           requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=1433): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))
```

Comment: Did you try http://localhost:1433

Comment: In the above, "service.hostname" is localhost and  "service.host_port" is 1433.  I think one issue is an HttpAdapter might not be appropriate for testing SQL server connectivity as I don't believe SQL Server uses http.

Comment: Dave is right. SQL server is not responding to HTTP requests. If it would be enough to check if SQL server is up and running, just make a telnet on port 1433 via telnetlib

Comment: The SOP way to check if a SQL Server instance is running si to check it's Windows service status.  I am not a pythonista so I cannot tell you how to do that in python.  Connecting to a database is not the recommended way because there are a variety of other things that that could prevent a specific user from connecting to a specific database, even if the instance is running.  It's also slower.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52341845/109122

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample function that will retry to connect to the DB and won't return until it has successfully connected or the defined `maxRetries` is reached:

```python
def waitDb(server, database, username, password, maxAttempts, waitBetweenAttemptsSeconds):
    """
    Returns True if the connection is successfully established before the maxAttempts number is reached
    Conversely returns False
    pyodbc.connect has a built-in timeout. Use a waitBetweenAttemptsSeconds greater than zero to add a delay on top of this timeout 
    """
    for attemptNumber in range(maxAttempts):
        cnxn = None
        try:
            cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
            cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        except Exception as e:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
        finally:
            if cnxn:
                print("The DB is up and running: ")
                return True
            else:
                print("DB not running yet on attempt numer " + str(attemptNumber))
            time.sleep(waitBetweenAttemptsSeconds)
    print("Max attempts waiting for DB to come online exceeded")
    return False
```

I wrote a minimal example here: https://github.com/claudiumocanu/flow-pytest-docker-compose-wait-mssql.

---

I included the three actions that can be executed independently, but you can jump to the last step specifically for what you asked:

**1. Connected from python to the mssql launched by the compose-file:**
For me it was quite annoying to find and install the appropriate ODBC Driver and its dependencies - `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` worked the best for me on Ubuntu 18.
To perform only this step, `docker-compose up` the the [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/claudiumocanu/flow-pytest-docker-compose-wait-mssql/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) in my example, then run the [example-connect.py](https://github.com/claudiumocanu/flow-pytest-docker-compose-wait-mssql/blob/master/example-connect.py)

**2. Created a function that attempts to connect to the DB with a maxAttemptsNumber and a delay between retries:**
Just run this [example-waitDb.py](https://github.com/claudiumocanu/flow-pytest-docker-compose-wait-mssql/blob/master/example-waitDb.py). You can play with the maxAttempts and the delayBetweenAttempts values, then bring up the database at randomly, to test it.

**3. Put everything together in the [test_db.py](https://github.com/claudiumocanu/flow-pytest-docker-compose-wait-mssql/blob/master/integration-tests/test_db.py) test suite:**

- the [waitDb](https://github.com/claudiumocanu/flow-pytest-docker-compose-wait-mssql/blob/3d21b7b5836ded7897035371ff71b006a289b599/integration-tests/test_db.py#L8) function described above.
- same [wrapper and annotations](https://github.com/claudiumocanu/flow-pytest-docker-compose-wait-mssql/blob/3d21b7b5836ded7897035371ff71b006a289b599/integration-tests/test_db.py#L32) that you provided in your example to spin-up the resources defined in the compose-file
- a dummy [integration test](https://github.com/claudiumocanu/flow-pytest-docker-compose-wait-mssql/blob/3d21b7b5836ded7897035371ff71b006a289b599/integration-tests/test_db.py#L42) that will not be executed before `waitDb` returns (if you want to block this tests completely, you can throw instead of returning False from the `waitDb` function)

PS: Keep using ENVs/vault etc rather than storing the real passwords like I did for the dummy example.

Answer (score 2):

```
if connection.is_connected():
    db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
    print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select database();")
    record = cursor.fetchone()
    print("You're connected to database: ", record)
```

you could use something like this and it would output if it was connected

Comment: Thanks.  I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to take what you have and plugging it into that "wait_for_api" fixture.  The "requests.Session()" has an exponential backoff thing going on so that it eventually figures out when the server is up.